# jQuery datepicker date of birth is null on post to controller

Tags: jquery, ajax, datepicker

I cannot understand why the date comes in null all the time.  Portion of my view:

```
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(x => x.Patient.DateOfBirth)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Patient.DateOfBirth, new { @id = "txtPatientDateOfBirth", @class = "normalText" })
            </td>
```

I load the date at first by finding the record via AJAX:

```
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.DateOfBirth) {
                $("#txtPatientDateOfBirth").datepicker("setDate", new Date(data.DateOfBirth));
            }
            if (data.ActiveDuty === "YES") {
                $("#ddlPatientStatus").val("Active Duty");
            }
            $("#divPatientPick").dialog('close');
            $("#txtPatientName").val(data.Name);
            $("#txtPatientName").show()
        }
```

Then I try to post it with AJAX:

```
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            data: $("#formPreArrival").serializeArray(),
            url: '@Url.Action("AddPreArrival")',
            success: function (data) {
                if (data.Errors === 'ERRORS') {
                    ErrorDialog("#MessageDialog", "#lblError", "There was an error detected in the submission of data.  Please try again later. ", "Error");
                    return false;
                }
                else {
                    ErrorDialog("#MessageDialog", "#lblError", "Patient Pre-Arrival data has been successfully entered. ", "Record Added");
                    $("#formPreArrival")[0].reset();
                    $('body, html').animate({ scrollTop: $('form').offset().top }, 'slow');
                    return false;
                }
            }
```

But the model field date of birth always shows up as null:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AddPreArrival(PreArrivalModel model)
    {
        string retval = "";
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var errors = ModelState.Where(x => x.Value.Errors.Count > 0).Select(x => new { x.Key, x.Value.Errors }).ToArray();
            model.Errors = "ERRORS";
            retval = "ERRORS";
            return Json(retval);
        }
        retval = Repository.AddPreArrival(model);

        return Json(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(retval));
    }
```

Portion of prearrival model:

```
    [Display(Name = "Transfer Category:")]
    public string CallTransferCategory { get; set; }

    public PatientModel Patient { get; set; }

    public TransferringFacilityModel TransferringFacility { get; set; }

    public UserModel User { get; set; }

    [Display(Name ="DEERS Verification: Is patient ELIGIBLE for care?")]
    public bool DeersVerify { get; set; }

    [Display(Name ="Comments:")]
    public string Notes { get; set; }

    public string Errors { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "DOB:")]
    public DateTime? DateOfBirth { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "DOB:")]
    public string DateOfBirthForDisplay
    {
        get
        {
            if (DateOfBirth.HasValue)
            {
                return DateOfBirth.Value.ToShortDateString();
            }
            return "";
        }
    }
```

Portion of Patient model:

```
    [Display(Name = "Age:")]
    public int Age
    {
        get
        {
            if (DateOfBirth.HasValue)
            {
                return DateTime.Today.Year - DateOfBirth.Value.Year;
            }
            return 0;
        }
    }

    [Display(Name = "DOB:")]
    public DateTime? DateOfBirth { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "DOB:")]
    public string DateOfBirthForDisplay
    {
        get
        {
            if (DateOfBirth.HasValue)
            {
                return DateOfBirth.Value.ToShortDateString();
            }
            return "";
        }
    }
```

Comment: try `$("#formPreArrival").serialize()` instead of `$("#formPreArrival").serializeArray()`

Comment: @ADyson - already tried that, same result.

Comment: can you show us what PreArrivalModel looks like please. Also doing a `console.log($("#formPreArrival").serialize());` might be useful as well

Comment: @ADyson - The patient model is part of the prearrival model.  What is strange is that if I add a DOB field to the prearrival model and use that field for the patient DOB, it comes into the action ok.  I then just fill the patient dob with that value.  Very strange why it ignores only the date field of a sub-model.

Comment: Not sure I understand. What is the Patient model and how is it related? The model being accepted by your action is PreArrivalModel. Can you post both models please?

Comment: @ADyson - added the relevant pieces

Comment: ok that seems to match up. What does `console.log($("#formPreArrival").serializeArray());` give you, if you place it just before the call to $.ajax?

Comment: @ADyson - I see the full array of all models, with all of the data.  The patient date is like '11/30/2010' but never makes it to the controller.

Comment: and is the patient date variable called "Patient.DateOfBirth"? Is the date format on the server side it's expecting the same as the client is sending (mm/dd/yyyy)?. I was hoping you would post the relevant parts of the output here. Sorry there are so many questions but this is a strange one.

Comment: @ADyson - Both models, the PreArrival and Patient models, have the exact same date structure.  It is a nullable date without a definition for format.  Both are initialized with the jQuery datepicker exactly the same.  yet the patient date comes to the controller action as null.  I really don't get it.

Comment: @ADyson - OK, another mystery this morning.  I had done an update to Visual Studio yesterday afternoon, especially the web tools installation, and now it is working at the patient level.

Comment: hmm. maybe there was a bug in the version you were running, related to dates, or date formats, in the model binder